# is there a way in css to make one div float over another but not float when scrolled down

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangle image and a circular image. The rectangle image needs to be 10em lower because of a banner image at the top. Half of the circle needs to be inside the rectangle and the other half outside the rectangle.
The center of the circle needs to be somewhat near with midpoint of the baseline of the rectangle.

Then the page has a bunch of texts on it. So, the circle needs to be relative to the rectangle but not the rest of the page. How would I accomplish that using CSS? This div literally shows above the image.

If I put a div or section around it messes with the layering. What am I missing?
(Also only CSS and HTML can be used)

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer{
    position:fixed;
    top:12em;
    left:0;
    width:80%;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    background-image: url(SOMEURL);
    }
    #inner{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        top: 300px;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url();
        background-size: cover;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 300px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
        -moz-border-radius: 300px;
    }
  </style>

<center>
  <div id=outer class="rectangle-Image-bg">
    <div id=inner >
    </div>
  </div>
<div>Some text here
<div>
</center>
```

Comment: You might try adding `position: relative` to `#outer` and `position: absolute` to `#inner`. Also `<center>` is deprecated and no longer recommended for use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and `position: absolute;` to solved your problem.

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 160px;
}

#inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ada4ad/fff");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 300px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>lorem</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div id=outer class="rectangle-Image-bg">
      <div id=inner>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>Some text here
      <div>
  </center>

  </div>
```